# Add another ckeditor in codeigniter using add button on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, ckeditor

I want to add another ckeditor whenever you click the add button another text field with ckeditor will be added. When click it added new field already but i cannot type on the new field with ckeditor. Here's my code:

*** View ***

```
                   <div id="addanother">
                        <?php echo $this->ckeditor->editor("textheading_lead[]",""); ?>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sel1">小見出し</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="subheading[]">
                                <option value="">監修 one</option>
                                <option value="">監修 two</option>
                                <option value="">監修 three</option>
                                <option value="">監修 four</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subheading_text[]">
                    </div>
                    <div id="addnewdiv"></div>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-info addfields" >+</a>
```

*** javascript ***

```
$('.addfields').on('click', addfields);
function addfields(e) {
  var new_input = $('#addanother').html();
  var aaa = new_input + '<br>';
  $('#addnewdiv').append(new_input);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

*** Controller ***

```
public function add_special(){
        $this->load->library('ckeditor');
        $this->load->library('ckfinder');
        $this->ckeditor->basePath = base_url().'asset/ckeditor/';

        $this->ckeditor->config['language'] = 'en';
        $this->ckeditor->config['width'] = '730px';
        $this->ckeditor->config['height'] = '300px';

        $this->ckfinder->SetupCKEditor($this->ckeditor,'../../asset/ckfinder/'); 

        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/special/add_special');
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
```

link of CKEditor package

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/

Comment: Add library doc link..

Comment: @MohammedShafeek what is it?

Comment: form where u downloaded the libraray ckeditor?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek from their website sir

Comment: add their link would be better for reference

Comment: edit the question title as per i recommended because it will reach more faster for those who are facing the same issue.

Comment: i was also facing this issue, it saved my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `ckeditor` plugin used to create dynamic id for editor panel. While appending div, plugin finds duplicate editor instances with same id `textheading_lead[]` and it was throwing error in your case. Here i made some alterations and will work for you.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><html lang="en">  
<head>
  <title>How to Integrate CKeditor in Codeigniter using Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Test57619322/here">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="addanother">
                <br>
                <?php echo $this->ckeditor->editor("textheading_lead[0]",""); ?>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel1">小見出し</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="subheading[]">
                        <option value="">監修 one</option>
                        <option value="">監修 two</option>
                        <option value="">監修 three</option>
                        <option value="">監修 four</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subheading_text[]">                
            </div>
            <div id="addnewdiv"></div>            
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-info addfields" >+ Add Fields</a>
            <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>

    </div>      
</form>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addfields').on('click', addfields);
    var i=0;
    function addfields(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var copy = $('#addanother').clone();

      var oneplus=i+1;

      $(copy).find('div#cke_textheading_lead\\[0\\]').remove();
      $(copy).find('script').remove();
      $(copy).find('textarea[name=textheading_lead\\[0\\]]').attr('name', 'textheading_lead['+oneplus+']');

      $('#addnewdiv').append($(copy).html()+ '<br>');
      CKEDITOR.replace('textheading_lead['+oneplus+']');
      i++;  

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can receive response in your controller like `$_POST["textheading_lead"]` or Codeigniter post method and as usual it gets as an array.

Comment: You are so amazing ^_^ it works! Thank you so much sir.